# Fingerprint not working

Tags: 20.04, error-handling, fingerprint-reader

I am using Acer Aspire 7 where I am not able to enrol my fingerprint.

error: failed to enrol fingerprint.

with lsusb command, I get
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c4f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

Comment: Two questions: (0) which version of Ubuntu are you running (1) are you comfortable editing a little bit of source code and recompiling? If you’re running 20.04, I can offer a step-by-step for this device.